# Запрос c замещением идентификаторов на значения из таблиц

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

В запросе из БД:

```
select * from sms where card_id = 10644617
```

я получаю строку где имеются `AuthorId` и `STATUS_ID`.

Эти две колонки возвращают мне `AuthorId` и `STATUS_ID` в численном виде.

Мне нужно, чтобы в каждой строке подставились данные из таблицы `Users.Name` по `ID` (`AuthorId` - выше), и для статуса соответсвенно таблица `DEFSMSSTATUS.Name` по `ID` (`STATUS_ID`- выше).

Как я понял тут JOIN не поможет, я просто сделаю разовый запрос и выведу результат.

А как сделать подмену `ID` на их значения из их таблиц?

Comment: Почему join не поможет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант с подзапросами, почти без джоинов

```
select      
  (select u.Name from Users u where u.id = sms.authorid) user_name,
  (select s.Name from DEFSMSSTATUS s where s.id = sms.status_id) status_name 
from sms 
where card_id = 10644617
```

Answer (score 3):

> Как я понял тут join не поможет

Нет, здесь он как раз кстати:

```sql
select sms.card_id, u.name, s.name
from sms 
join users u on u.authorid = sms.authorid 
join defsmsstatus s on s.status_id = sms.status_id
where card_id = 10644617
```